# iScroll will not zoom in cordova applications

Tags: javascript, cordova, iscroll

I have been attempting to have a tab in my cordova app in which a map is shown.  I want users to be able to pinch to zoom in and out of the image and pan.  I used the latest iScroll build and I wasn't able to get anything to work correctly.  I have recently come across this demo

http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/zoom/

Which does exactly what I want my app to do and works in my phone's browser.  However, when I copied the iscroll.js and source of this demo and pasted it into my app to test it through cordova, I was not able to zoom on my android phone or ios emulator, only pan around.  I have achieved the same on the page I actually want to apply this to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { 
            zoom:true,
            onBeforeScrollStart:null,
            zoomMin:0.25,
            zoomStart:0.5,
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">


    html {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    }

    body {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    }

    #scroller {
    position:relative;
    background: #ccc;
    /*-webkit-touch-callout:none;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

    width:725px;
    padding:0;
    }

    img {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body Onload="loaded()">
    <ons-screen>
        <ons-navigator title="Map">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="scroller">
                    <!--<iframe src="thing.html" style="width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>-->
                    <img src="img/map.png"></img>
                </ons-page>
            </div>
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-screen>
</body>
<!--<script src="js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myLogic.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

If anyone can help me figure out why this works in browser, but not when translated to native code, or how to make it work, I will be forever in your debt.

Comment: Oh, the commented scripts at the bottom are from when I attempted to solve this using hammer.js...

Comment: UPDATE: I pasted in the iScroll5 demo exactly as I had done with the iScroll4 demo, and it performed even worse, this stuff is a mess, probably won't be using a framework like this again.  Best to just write it twice.